# How to write reduce with lambda function for pyspark data-frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, pyspark

I wanted to implement reduce function with lambda . for example if there is pyspark data-frame and on some column, I want to get all the records for those column value lengths is between some range. How this could be implemented using reduce function with lambda.
I tried to implement it with the below code, but I am not pretty sure about this.

```
bad_df = reduce(lambda x, (min < f.col(x) < max for x in df.columns if x in col_list))
```

`col_list` has list of columns for which I want to check if column value is within range.

Answer (score 0):

From question and approach, I am understanding that you want to verify if all columns in `col_list` have values within `(min, max)`.

#### Solution

```py
total = df.count
ans = True

for col_name in col_list:
    
    #check if all values of that column lie within the range
    match_count = df.where(min < col(col_name) < max).count

    
    ans = count == match_count
    
    #if not then no need to go further
    if not ans:
         break
```

Comment: I wanted to solve this problem using reduce with lambda function .Solution provided by you ,  I was  able to write program for the problem  .

Comment: Lambda reduce is inefficient here, if first column from col_list does not meet the criteria then you should stop there. Lambda reduce will evaluate everything and return false eventually (not short-circuited).